# TinyMce copies the classes from the current block element when pressing Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

When using tinyMce in Wordpress, In the visual editor, I'f I'm entering content in an element and press return the classes from the parent element are copied over, i would want simply to create a new `<p>` element.

For example, I'm editing

```
<p class="blip blip--gray one-sixth push-huge--top push--bottom">d aasdas d</p>
```

Then i press return and the following is added:

```
<p class="blip blip--gray one-sixth push-huge--top push--bottom"></p>
```

where i would want only to add

```
<p></p>
```

I have `forced_root_block` option set to `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete answer, based on @thariama post is

```
        tinyMCE.editors.content.on('keyup',function(e){
            if ( 13 === e.keyCode ) {
               $(tinyMCE.editors.content.selection.getNode()).closest('p').removeAttr('class');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is tinymce default behaviour.

You could add a tinymce handler to your editor that gets triggered by the `keyup` event. Testing for `charCode 13` you can detect if ENTER has been pressed. If so you could remove the classes from the actual paragraph in the editor:

```
$(tinymce.get('youreditor_id').getNode()).closest('p').removeAttr('class');
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be the solution to this problem:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  keep_styles: false
});
```

[tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#keep_styles) - content filtering docs

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, but I had tried it in Wordpress 4.3.1 and couldn't get it to work